# Why Is This Ruby While Statement Not Working

Tags: ruby, rspec, page-object-gem

Background: This is using page-object, and Rspec. The page, objects are setup correctly. Basically what is happening is its skipping the while statement and going directly to checking of the variable `label` exists on the page.

What it SHOULD do is check if the `label` variable is on the page and if not then wait 20 seconds and refresh the page then check again for up to 30 times and if it fails on the 30th time then it should fail all together. If it finds it then it should check again and pass it.

```
def check_label(label, current_page)
  labels_filter_element.click
  check_label_sla(label, current_page)
  current_page.text.should include label
end

def check_label_sla(label, current_page)
  t = 30
  i = 0
  while i < t
    if current_page.text.should include label
      return
    else
      sleep(20)
      current_page.refresh
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I think what is happening is if `current_page.text.should include label` is always returning TRUE, but I'm not sure. If more info is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the following assumptions:

- The behaviour you are seeing is that the page is first loaded, the labels_filter_element is clicked, the label is not on the page and the test fails immediately without refreshing the page.
- `label` is a string

Given these assumptions, the problem is with the if-statement:

```
if current_page.text.should include label
```

When the if statement is executed, it will assert that the page includes the label:

- If the page has the label, the code in the if will be executed (ie it will immediately return and the assertion in `check_label` will pass).
- In the case that the page does not have the label, the assertion will throw an exception causing the test to fail immediately (ie the else code will not get executed). So the test is failing inside the `check_label_sla` method, not at the end of the `check_label method` (which makes it seem like the while loop is not working).

You want the if statement to check that the text is included, without making an assertion. Therefore you want:

```
if current_page.text.include? label
```

So your `check_label_sla` method would become:

```
def check_label_sla(label, current_page)
  t = 30
  i = 0
  while i < t
    if current_page.text.include? label
      return
    else
      sleep(20)
      current_page.refresh
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Or you could reduce it to:

```
def check_label_sla(label, current_page)
  30.times do
    return if current_page.text.include? label
    sleep(20)
    current_page.refresh
  end
end
```